# Validate HTML tag in Java using Jericho

Tags: java, html, validation, jericho-html-parser

Using the Jericho API, can I validate a given HTML tag like `<input type="test" .....>`? I was unable to find an API in Jericho that would do so. Is there a way where I could do that using Jericho only?

I don't want to tidy or Sanitise the HTML tag. I just want to check for its validity.

Answer (score 0):

The Jericho API will log all the validations telling you all your flaws and gaps in the constructed HTML you are validating. It does its own version of tag tidying but also logs that information of it's version of the logger.

Let's try to print what Jericho thinks about your `html` tag:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);
WriterLogger myLogger = new WriterLogger(writer);
myLogger.setInfoEnabled(true);
        
Source source = new Source("<input type=\"test\" .....>");
source.setLogger(myLogger);

try {
    source.getSourceFormatter().writeTo(writer);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output which I get is:

> ERROR: StartTag input at (r1,c1,p0) contains attribute name with invalid first character at position (r1,c20,p19)
> `<input type="test" .....>`

This log entry looks to be parsable and can be used in more than one way.